# Transfer XAMPP local Wordpress website from one PC to another

Tags: localhost, xampp

I use XAMPP to build my wordpress site locally. How can I transfer my website to another computer and continue the build from there also locally?

Comment: You'd do it the same way as switching hosts (without changing URL). Either copy the files + db or use one of the many duplicator/backup+restore plugins

Comment: Copy files and db from where?

Comment: From where they currently are (your local machine). Did you search for this? I imagine "WP move site xampp" / "WP migrate site xampp" should give some results